# Prove the following tautology: $\big[(p\leftrightarrow q) \land (\lnot q \to r) \land (p \to r)\big]\to r $

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> Prove the following tautology:
>
> $$\big[(p\leftrightarrow q) \land (\lnot q \to r) \land (p \to
>  r)\big]\to r $$

**My effort**

I am trying to prove this with a direct reasoning,i.e without using truth tables.

Now since $ \lnot q \to r $ and $p \to r $ ,I think it follows that I can rewrite $$\big[(p\leftrightarrow q) \land (\lnot q \to r) \land (p \to
 r)\big]=\big[(p \land \lnot q) \to r \big] \to r $$

which would be the proof for it,but I am not so sure :I just started studying  math logic.

In what other ways (excluding truth table) could this problem be solved  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a good direct reasoning method with a different starting point. Reminder that we need to confirm that *if* all the statements on the LHS are true, *then* the statement on the RHS is true. So we will assume the LHS is true and see if that forces $r$ to hold.

Consider $p\iff q$. Then either both are true or both are false. If both are true, then since $p\Rightarrow r$, we have that $r$ holds. If both are false, then since $\neg q \Rightarrow r$, we have that $r$ holds. Thus the entire expression implies $r$.

So why does this prove what we are interested in? I am establishing that, given the truth of the LHS, it follows that $r$ must hold. Put another way, if $\neg r$ was to hold, it would be contradictory. If we recall the definition of $A\Rightarrow B$, we see that $A\Rightarrow B$ holds if and only if $\neg A$ holds or ($A$ holds and $B$ holds).

You never have to worry about the $\neg A$ case, because the relationship between $A$ and $B$ is irrelevant. If $\neg A$ is possible, then the implication holds for values that make it so. If $\neg A$ never holds (so $A$ is a tautology) then that case of the implication is trivially or vacuously true.

So, we need to concern ourselves with both $A$ and $B$ holding. To this end, I showed that if $A$ holds, it logically follows that $B$ holds. Thus for $A$ to hold but not $B$ would be a logical contradiction, as we desire.

Comment: Why you don't assume that $r$ is false even in the LHS ?Don't we need to give all of $p,q,r$ a true or false "state" ?(I guess it will take to the same reasoning,but why ?)

Comment: You could do that, but at that point your basically doing a truth table in your head. I expanded my answer greatly with explanation

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\small\begin{align}
\big[(p\leftrightarrow q) \land (\lnot\, q \to r) \land (p \to
 r)\big]\to r
&
\equiv
\big[(p\to q)\land(q\to p)\land (\lnot\,(\lnot\, q) \lor r) \land (\lnot\, p \lor 
r)\big]\to r \\
&
\equiv
\big[(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land(\lnot\, q\lor p)\land (\lnot\,(\lnot\, q) \lor r) \land (\lnot\, p \lor 
r)\big]\to r \\
&
\equiv
\big[(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land(\lnot\, q\lor p)\land (q \lor r) \land (\lnot\, p \lor 
r)\big]\to r \\
&
\equiv
\big[(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land r \land (p \lor\lnot\, 
p)\big]\to r \\
&
\equiv
\big[(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land(\lnot\, p\lor q)\land r\big]\to r. \\
\end{align}$$

Is $\small[\,\mathrm{P}(p,q)\land r\,]\to r$ a tautology? Can you proceed further?

Comment: What property are you using in the fourth line ?

Comment: @Mr.Y The Distributive law: $$\rm (P\lor Q)\land(P\lor R)\equiv P\land(Q\lor R).$$

Answer (score 1):

A natural deduction proof:

1. Assume (p↔q)∧(¬q→r)∧(p→r)
2. Infer (p↔q),(¬q→r), and (p→r) by conjunction elimination
3. Assume q, infer r, discharge to get (q→r)
4. You now have the consequences (¬q→r) and (q→r)
5. Infer r by disjunction elimination from (p or ¬p)
6. Discharge

Answer (score 1):

A proof by resolution

1. Start from the corresponding  set of clauses $\{(¬p\vee q),(¬q\vee p),(q\vee r),( \neg p \vee r)\}$
2. Resolve clauses 2 and 4 to produce clause 5:  $(¬q \vee r)$
3. Resolve  clause 3 and 5 to get (r)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a natural deduction proof in a Fitch-style proof checker:

[image]

The law of the excluded middle (LEM) on $Q \lor \neg Q$ is referenced at the end.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/